# Multiple Audio Inputs in p5.js

Tags: javascript, audio, p5.js

Help help help, I have a project with two other students and we are working in P5.js. So for the project we need two seperate Audio Inputs, but we don't get how to define different audio inputs, can anybody help us? (p.s. we already got the default mic, which is the MacBook microphone, to work. What we need now is a second input from a wireless mic. Is there any way to do this?)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: SO is not  a good platform for this question sadly. Engage with the staff at your institute, they are paid to help and should be able to provide support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scan the sources by `getSources()` method and use the `setSource([int])` to set the input source for separate audio inputs.

Then you need to use the `connect()` method to connect these audio inputs into the master output.

The example in the official docs is quite helpful: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.AudioIn/getSources